# Paralax gradient + transform css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you please tell me how I can make the text colour change when scrolling depending on the background gradient and increase when scrolling?

Right now, either gradient or zoom works.

Added clarity and showed two code examples that work either this way or that way.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var mass = Math.min(20, 1 + 0.005 * $(this).scrollTop());
  $('div').css('transform', 'scale(' + mass + ')');
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 20%, red 70%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

span {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>TEST</span></div>
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 20%, red 70%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

span {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div><span>TEST</span></div>
```

Comment: instead of using `transform: scale` you could try and increase the font-size on scroll

Comment: @LS_ I can use Zoom as well, but then the text will carry over.

Answer (score 0):

maybe so?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var mass = Math.min(20, 1 + 0.005 * $(this).scrollTop());
  $('div').css('transform', 'scale(' + mass + ')');
  $('div').css('filter', 'hue-rotate(' + mass + 'turn)'); /*!!!!!!!*/
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 20%, red 70%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

span {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>TEST</span></div>
```